# When referring to key types and lengths, is there a correct order to stating the type and length?

Tags: documentation

When referring to key types and lengths, is there a correct order to stating the type and length?

For example, would I use "2048-bit RSA key" or "RSA 2048-bit key" in documentation? Or just simply be consistent with whatever I choose to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one has about 4x as many search results, and seems more natural to me (both written and spoken). There are some [grammar guides](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) that say the normal ordering would be size before type:

> If we don’t want to emphasise any one of the adjectives, the most usual sequence of adjectives is:
> 2. Size
> [...]
> 9. Type

But there doesn't really seem to be a defined standard or agreement in technical writing - you can find it written both ways in different RFCs. For example:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6584

> For instance, the following key lengths provide equivalent security: a 1024-bit RSA key versus a 160-bit ECC key, or a **2048-bit RSA key** versus a 224-bit ECC key.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9142

> In order to match the 112 bits of security strength needed for 3des-cbc, an **RSA 2048-bit key** matches the security strength.

But whichever way to write it the meaning is perfectly clear, so as long as you're consistent about your style then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I think 2048-bit RSA key makes more sense. Breaking out each one, 2048-bit kind of tells us something. RSA key kind of tells us something. 2048-bit key doesn't really tell us anything, so 2048-bit RSA key seems the most correct, and it even aligns with that more general and very helpful grammar guide.